# How to auto-scale UIImage size in UIImageView?

Tags: iphone

As I try to put UIImage into a UIImageView, UIImageView auto-expended to display real image size. Is there a solution to have image auto-scale according to UIImageView's size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that either in IB or in your code directly be setting UIImageView's `contentMode` property to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` (see UIView class documentation for other possible values of `UIViewContentMode` enumeration).